# Batch md command

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to copy contents of a cd to x86 of my computer. When I run my script it says "A subdirectory or file \Navel already exists". When I navigate to my x86 folder my file isnt there. How do i fix this.

```
cd %ProgramFiles(x86)%\
md \Navel
pause
```

Comment: md is for creating directory.What  do you want to copy?

Comment: I'm going to copy contents of a cd to the dir Navel

Comment: If you current drive is not the same that `%ProgramFiles(x86)%` points to then the `cd` command will change the current active directory on that drive, but you will continue on your current drive. If this is could be the case try with `cd /d "%ProgramFiles(x86)%"` to change folder and drive

Comment: I'm still getting the same error even w/ admin

Comment: To create `Navel` folder _in current directory_ use `md Navel`. If you insert a back-slash before Navel this way: `md \Navel`, it is created _in the root directory_ of current drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create `Navel` folder in current directory use `md Navel`. If you insert a back-slash before Navel this way: `md \Navel`, it is created *in the root directory* of current drive. Try:

```
cd "%ProgramFiles(x86)%"
md Navel
xcopy E:\Project\*.* Navel 
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

The command for copying directories (including subdirectories) is

```
xcopy <source> <destination> /E
```

You need to replace `<source>` with your CD-drive name (e.g. `E:\Project`), and replace `<destination>` with the target directory (i.e. `%programFiles(x86)%\Navel`). So in your case it should be something like

```
@echo off
if not exist "%programFiles(x86)%\Navel" (
  mkdir "%programFiles(x86)%\Navel"
)
xcopy E:\project "%programFiles(x86)%\Navel" /E
```

The command `md` creates a directory if it does not exist yet.
So `md Navel` creates the directory *Navel*. Of course, if it already exists, it will not create it again.

Comment: Then I need more information. How exactly did you execute it ? What is the name of your CD drive ? is it `D:` or something else ?

Comment: My drive name is E:/. I did: xcopy E:\Project\* %ProgramFiles(x86)%Navel
But I got it now

Comment: Is `Project` a directory on your E drive ?

Answer (score 0):

There are only 2 situations why this error occurs:
1. the directory 'Navel' exists in the root dir of the current drive
2. there is already a FILE called 'Navel' in the root directory of the current drive

I think you intend to create that directory in the program dir, not in the root. But your code checks only in the root directory because of the leading backslash before 'Navel'.